# Greedy Maximum Flow

Tags: algorithm, greedy, max-flow

The **Dining Problem**:
Several families go out to dinner together. In order to increase their social interaction, they would like to sit at tables so that no two members of the same family are at the same table. Assume that the dinner contingent has `p` families and that the `i`th family has `a(i)` members. Also, assume there are `q` tables available and that the `j`th table has a seating capacity of `b(j)`.

**The question is:**
What is the maximum number of persons we can sit on the tables?

EDIT:
This problem can be solved creating a Graph and running a **maximum flow** algorithm. But if we have 2*10^3 vertices with Dinic algorithm, the global complexity is O(10^6*10^6) = O(10^12).

If we only sit always the larger groups first, in a greedy manner. The complexity is O(10^6).

So my questions are:

1) Does the greedy approach in this problem work?

2) What is the best algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: This is probably a better question for Computer Science SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to come up with examples where such seating is simply impossible, so here's a pseudo code for solving the problem assuming that the problem is solvable:

```
Sort each family i by a(i) in decreasing order
Add each table j to a max-heap with b(j) as the key

For each family i from the sorted list:
    Pop a(i) tables from max-heap
    Add one member of i to each table
    Add each table j back into the max-heap with b(j) = b(j) - 1
```

Let `n = a(1) + a(2) + ... + a(p)` (i.e. total number of people)

Assuming a binary heap is used for the max-heap, the time complexities are:

- Sorting families: `O(plog(p))`
- Initializing max-heap of tables: `O(qlog(q))`
- All pops and pushes to/from max-heap: `O(nlog(q))`

Giving the total time complexity of `O(plog(p) + qlog(q) + nlog(q))`, where `O(nlog(q))` will likely dominate.

Since we are dealing with integers, if we use a 1D bucket system for the max-heap such that `c` is the maximum `b(j)`, then we will end up with just `O(n + c)` (assuming the max-heap operations dominate), which maybe quicker.

Finally, please up-vote David's answer as the proof was required and is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, greedily seating the largest families first is a correct solution. We just need to prove that, after we seat the next largest family, there is a way to seat the remaining families correctly.

Suppose that an instance is solvable. We prove by induction that there exists a solution after the greedy algorithm seats the `k` largest families. The basis `k = 0` is obvious, since the hypothesis to be proved is that there exists a solution. Inductively, suppose that there exists a solution that extends greedy's partial assignment for the first `k - 1` families. Now greedy extends its partial assignment by seating the `k`th family. We edit the known solution to restore the inductive hypothesis.

While we still can, find a table `T1` where greedy has seated a `k`th family member but the known solution has not. If there is space in the known solution at `T1`, move a `k`th family member from a table where greedy has none. Otherwise, the known solution has a family member not in the `k` largest families seated at `T1`. Since that family is smaller than the `k`th largest, a `k`th largest family member occupies a table `T2` that the smaller family does not. Swap these members.